# Java Code to correct UTF-8 Coded Field Back to 8 Bit ASCII

Tags: java, utf-8, ascii, 8-bit

I have some data I'm processing with JAVA. From the looks of the data, it seems an 8 bit ASCII name was encoded using UTF-8 but stored in ASCII.

Value in the datafield: "JosÃ© Flores"
What should have been stored: "José Flores"

To validate my suspicion, I ran this code:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = c_TOBETRANSLATED.getBytes("UTF-8");
String s2 = new String(utf8Bytes);
```

When `TOBETRANSLATED` = "José Flores", it returns back "JosÃ© Flores".  So it appears my datafield is UTF-8 coded.  So to try to convert the data back to ASCII, I was trying this code:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = c_TOBETRANSLATED.getBytes("ASCII");
String s2 = new String(utf8Bytes);
```

When `TOBETRANSLATED` = "JosÃ© Flores", it returns back "JosÃƒÂ© Flores".

What am I doing wrong?
I need `TOBETRANSLATED` = "JosÃ© Flores" to return back "José Flores".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = c_TOBETRANSLATED.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); String s2 = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: That works perfect.  For my data that was incorrectly saved in UTF-8 format, it correctly returned it back.  However it now creates a new problem.  Some of my records are stored correctly in 8 bit ASCII.  So if I let them run through that code, they wind up corrupted.

Comment: Example, one record will say "JosÃ© Flores" and now returns "José Flores". The next record was corrected and contained "José Romero" but falls through the code to become "Jos� Romero". Is there a conditional test that would detect the UTF-8 so I can only translate those records?